# Got error 404 from a and app and servlet after restart tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu

When I've restarted tomcat using `sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart` or `sudo service tomcat7 restart` my app (not only servlet but static files too) in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/code` is returning 404 errors why? (it work when I restart my laptop).

I'm using Xubuntu with OpenJDK and tomcat 7.

I'm not using any IDE like Eclipse, I compile java files using javac from command line.

I've installed `Tomcat Web Application Manager` and it shows error:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /code could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/code]]
```

Comment: Check the `catalina.out` log file.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for the hint, I have exception backtrace with this `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thetransactioncompany/jsonrpc2/JSONRPC2ParseException`

Comment: You'll have to put jsonrpc2 jar in tomcat's lib folder.